# In Cocos2d, how to release texture from OpenGL memory(GPU)?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

```
CCSprite *sprite;
sprite.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"mySpriteImage.png"];
sprite.position = ccp(width/2.0f, height/2.0f);
[self addChild:sprite z:2 tag:kTagMySprite];

...

[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

Is there a memory leak in the code above? Is the OpenGL texture released, or does it need to be released from the cache?

Comment: You don't initialize the sprite! Thus your code can crash!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most questions can be answered by using the right tool. In this case, stackoverflow is not the tool. [Instruments is](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).

You can also approach this with Vulcan logic. This piece of code is being used by thousands of developers worldwide. The probability of this code causing a memory leak has to be considered [infinitesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) for a software library that has existed for over 3 years.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I don't have device certificate, not able to attach simulator build to instrument. So asked here and confused with your answer.

Comment: CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"raj.png"] ;
sprite.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"mySpriteImage.png"];
sprite.position = ccp(width/2.0f, height/2.0f);
[self addChild:sprite z:2 tag:kTagMySprite];

...

[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

Comment: In runtime texture cache is changed. So what about previous texture? released or not?

Comment: You don't need a device certificate to run Instruments. In this case you add a texture to the cache. You don't remove any texture. So it stays in memory until possibly the device receives a memory warning at which point cocos2d by default removes all unused textures.

Comment: Thank u Sir,  [sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]  won't remove opengl texture? then which call help me to release texture in cache? (in above code)

Answer (score 1):

I got solution, One of these call removes texture from `CCTextureCache` and that removes OpenGL texture (glGenTextures id) .

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:sprite3.texture];

OR

[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTextureForKey:@"ImageName.png"];

OR

[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:[(CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:kTagBackground] texture] ];
```